# Get the original script name of a python executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a program coded in python named: "main.exe"
And I would like to know the name of the script it had before being convert into an executable.

In case the executable has been renamed, it doesn't have the same name as the original script.

I hope you understood me.
An example to illustrate:

```
get_original_name(main.exe)
-> script.py
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you can access the name of the `py` file via:

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

If you were to compile this code and give the `exe` a new name with pyinstaller, the original script name will be printed.

Comment: Yes I had already seen this solution, but it is only when you have the source code

Answer (score 0):

It is Not Possible, Since the Filename and the Compiled Program Have No Link,

But tools like [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) Can get you alot of information about that particular Program, and it can be used in other things Too

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, too bad we have to use third party programs, but thanks for your answer ;)